# Вывод типа результата функции

Tags: c++, c++14

Пытаюсь вывести тип результата одной функции и подставить его в аргумент другой + добавить ссылку:

```
struct A {
    auto foo(int) const {
        return 42;
    }

    void bar(std::result_of_t<decltype(foo(int{}))>& i) {}
};
```

Однако получаю много ошибок компиляции. Как сделать правильно для любого типа результата (не только `int`)?

Answer (score 4):

```
auto foo(int) const {
    return 42;
}
```

это уже сразу С++14, но не С++11.

При этом дедукция типа `auto` будет выполнена только после завершения определения класса, по каковой причине определить возвращаемый тип `foo` внутри определения класса не получится (если не рассматривать внутренность тел методов).

Если вы явно укажете тип

```
auto foo(int) const -> int {
    return 42;
}
```

то будет работать

```
void bar(std::result_of_t<decltype(&A::foo)(A, int)>& i) {}
```

Попытка сделать

```
void bar(decltype(foo(int{}))>& i) {}
```

не пройдет, потому что ссылаться на `foo` без объекта в этом месте запрещается. А "потенциальный" вариант

```
void bar(decltype(std::declval<A>().foo(int{}))>& i) {}
```

не проходит из-за незавершенности типа `A`.

Comment: Ваш вариант [не работает](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/L6pN2AwkNORiFZEU) для `auto` возвращаемого типа.

Comment: @alexolut: Да, это так. Исправил ответ.

Comment: Потеряли константность foo во втором куске кода.

Comment: @alexolut: Да, спасибо, переупорядочил.

Comment: всегда рад помочь :)